# Discord Privileged Intents list breakdown with v9 API and V13 discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm in the process of updating my bot for Intents.  I am also at the point where I need to get verified, and have completed that, except for the intents part.  I have looked all over for the information about intents, to properly educate myself, but I am missing something basic.

The bot has switches for:

```
PRESENCE INTENT
SERVER MEMBERS INTENT
```

(there's also info about upcoming messages intent that hits the "fall" of 2021)

in the below listing, there is no place I can find that actually matches the above 2 INTENT flags in the bot config, to the actual map of lists below.  There is a paragraph with this:

```
Message content will become a privileged intent in 2022. Learn more here.
Some intents are defined as "Privileged" due to the sensitive nature of the data. Those intents are:

GUILD_PRESENCES
GUILD_MEMBERS
```

so the question is, does "GUILD_PRESENCES" = PRESENCE_INTENT, and "GUILD_MEMBERS" = SERVER_MEMBERS_INTENT?  I think so...but it would seem really easy to just make the names match...

discord developer info has this link:
https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#privileged-intents

This is the list of intents provided:

```
List of Intents
GUILDS (1 << 0)
  - GUILD_CREATE
  - GUILD_UPDATE
  - GUILD_DELETE
  - GUILD_ROLE_CREATE
  - GUILD_ROLE_UPDATE
  - GUILD_ROLE_DELETE
  - CHANNEL_CREATE
  - CHANNEL_UPDATE
  - CHANNEL_DELETE
  - CHANNEL_PINS_UPDATE
  - THREAD_CREATE
  - THREAD_UPDATE
  - THREAD_DELETE
  - THREAD_LIST_SYNC
  - THREAD_MEMBER_UPDATE
  - THREAD_MEMBERS_UPDATE *
  - STAGE_INSTANCE_CREATE
  - STAGE_INSTANCE_UPDATE
  - STAGE_INSTANCE_DELETE

GUILD_MEMBERS (1 << 1)
  - GUILD_MEMBER_ADD
  - GUILD_MEMBER_UPDATE
  - GUILD_MEMBER_REMOVE
  - THREAD_MEMBERS_UPDATE *

GUILD_BANS (1 << 2)
  - GUILD_BAN_ADD
  - GUILD_BAN_REMOVE

GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS (1 << 3)
  - GUILD_EMOJIS_UPDATE
  - GUILD_STICKERS_UPDATE

GUILD_INTEGRATIONS (1 << 4)
  - GUILD_INTEGRATIONS_UPDATE
  - INTEGRATION_CREATE
  - INTEGRATION_UPDATE
  - INTEGRATION_DELETE

GUILD_WEBHOOKS (1 << 5)
  - WEBHOOKS_UPDATE

GUILD_INVITES (1 << 6)
  - INVITE_CREATE
  - INVITE_DELETE

GUILD_VOICE_STATES (1 << 7)
  - VOICE_STATE_UPDATE

GUILD_PRESENCES (1 << 8)
  - PRESENCE_UPDATE

GUILD_MESSAGES (1 << 9)
  - MESSAGE_CREATE
  - MESSAGE_UPDATE
  - MESSAGE_DELETE
  - MESSAGE_DELETE_BULK

GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS (1 << 10)
  - MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD
  - MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE
  - MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE_ALL
  - MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE_EMOJI

GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING (1 << 11)
  - TYPING_START

DIRECT_MESSAGES (1 << 12)
  - MESSAGE_CREATE
  - MESSAGE_UPDATE
  - MESSAGE_DELETE
  - CHANNEL_PINS_UPDATE

DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS (1 << 13)
  - MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD
  - MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE
  - MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE_ALL
  - MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE_EMOJI

DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING (1 << 14)
  - TYPING_START
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT` is `GUILD_MEMBERS` and `GUILD_PRESENCES` is `PRESENCE INTENT`.